# ReviewBoard2.0.12 failing to install

Tags: linux, easy-install, review-board

I'm trying to install ReviewBoard2.0.12 on an Ubuntu 12.04 server and am getting a bizarre outcome
I don't get an error
easy_install is finding the file and downloading it, however it is not installing it so its not located in my dist-Packages directory (my current default)
When I use easy_install on other tools there is no issue 
Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks !

Comment: Please consider using `pip` over `easy_install`. Pip comes with much better error handling.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the review board documentation. 
https://www.reviewboard.org/docs/manual/dev/admin/installation/linux/

if you are not clear, Please refer this link to install review board on Ubuntu https://bianchirick.wordpress.com/2014/07/09/installing-reviewboard-2-0-x-on-ubuntu-12-04-x/

Still if you are facing any issues further. Please provide more details... error log, python version...

Comment: Unfortunately those were the first options I exhausted when running into this problem. Like I stated before, it is downloading via easy_install, but not installing. So the output is: error: none. However, when I use pip, I get a timeout error.